# Redirect MATLAB standard output for system command

Tags: matlab

I am running a `test.bat` file using the following code in MATLAB.

```
system('C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /K "test.bat"');
```

I don't want the output to be shown in MTLAB console.Also how can I redirect it's output to a file without using `diary`?

Answer (score 3):

Either you can embed the redirection into the command line:

```
system('C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /K "test.bat" > out.txt');
```

or store the result into variable:

```
[status, result] = system('C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /K "test.bat" );
```

And then `fprintf` the `result` to file.